# Ways in which one can develop a modern API Web Sevice which is Enterprise level and Scalable

Tags: rest, web-services, enterprise

This is more of a general type of question. There are multiple ways in which one can develop API's to exchange data. For example:
Python Flask, Apache Camel, Node.js, etc

And using Testing tools like:
SoapUI, Postman, Swagger editor.

My question is what are the pros and cons of developing different types of API at Enterprise level to handle heavy load, is Scalable and Future proof

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are doing.
Is the system growing in number of transactions, size of transactions, number of clients, complexity of request or what?
Can the requests be done in parallel or are there shared resources?
Are requests coming from a variety of locations or networks?

How much are you willing to spend?

All are important considerations.